# how to recieve mail using maven javax?

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I want to receive mail from any specified email id  using javafx but getting an exception that is   MojoExecutionException.
 my pom.xml dependencies and whole source code provided below please help me to solve this problem.

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0-b01</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
<groupId>org.jvnet.mock-javamail</groupId>
<artifactId>mock-javamail</artifactId>
<version>1.9</version>
```

And my Javax code is

```
 try {


 Properties properties = new Properties();  
 properties.put("mail.pop3.host", pop3Host);  
 Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);  

POP3Store emailStore = (POP3Store) emailSession.getStore(storeType);  
emailStore.connect(user, password);  

 //3) create the folder object and open it  
 Folder emailFolder = emailStore.getFolder("INBOX");  
 emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);  

 //4) retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it  
  Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();  
 for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {  
 Message message = messages[i];  
 System.out.println("---------------------------------");  
 System.out.println("Email Number " + (i + 1));  
 System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());  
 System.out.println("From: " + message.getFrom()[0]);  
 System.out.println("Text: " + message.getContent().toString());  
 }  

 //5) close the store and folder objects  
 emailFolder.close(false);  
 emailStore.close();  

  } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {e.printStackTrace();}   
  catch (MessagingException e) {e.printStackTrace();}  
 catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}  
}  

public  void excute() throws MessagingException {  

 String host = "xyz.com";//change accordingly  
 String mailStoreType = "pop3";  
 String username= "xyz@pqr.com";  
  String password= "cccccc";  

 receiveEmail(host, mailStoreType, username, password);  

 }  
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

Parent root=FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Scene.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    scene.getStylesheets().add("/styles/Styles.css");

    stage.setTitle("JavaFX and Maven");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException {
     receiveEmail obj=new receiveEmail();
     obj.excute();
     launch(args);
  }
```

Comment: Please post the complete error that you get.

Comment: Im getting this error after running my code :Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project send_recv_sms: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException